# bash: merge (interleave) two files inserting the first line of 2nd, before the first occurence of string in 1st...

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to merge two files that look like File1 and File2 to something resembling Result. The aim is to use a pattern in File1 and insert the 1st line of File 2 in the line before the pattern in File 1, and recursively work through both files.

## File1

```
Input:
Processed:
Result:
Input:
Result:
Input:
Error:
Result:
...
```

## File2

```
Process1
Process2
Process3
…
```

## Result

```
Process1
Input:
Processed:
Result:
Process2
Input:
Result:
Process3
Input:
Error:
Result:
...
```

So far this will insert the line from File2 on the line *below* the occurrence of the pattern not above:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}1;/Input:/{print a[++i]}' File2 File2
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want a *bash* answer or an *awk* answer?

Comment: The `1` sould be the last character of your awk line. First you print what you stored in the array `a` and then the entry. So `awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}/Input:/{print a[++i]}1' File2 File1`

Comment: Apologies I should have been clearer - I would like an awk answer (but its going in a bash script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're almost there

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{p[NR]=$0; next} /^Input:/{print p[++c]}1' file2 file1

Process1
Input:
Processed:
Result:
Process2
Input:
Result:
Process3
Input:
Error:
Result:
```

you want to print the line after the insertion, so remove print line to the end, which is `1` as shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to insert a line from File2 above each line matching `Input:` from File1.

The below will do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*|4.0.*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.1 or newer required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

exec {file1_fd}<File1 # open File1 for input, storing the FD# it's opened on in file1_fd
exec {file2_fd}<File2 # likewile for File2 and file2_fd

while IFS= read -r f1line <&"$file1_fd"; do  # as long as we can read a line from file1...
  if [[ $f1line =~ Input: ]]; then           # if that line contains "Input:"
    IFS= read -r f2line <&"$file2_fd"        # ...then read a second line from file2
    printf '%s\n' "$f2line"                  # ...and write that second line to our output
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$f1line"                    # before writing the content from file1.
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/Input:/=' file1 |
paste - file2 |
sed -nr 's/(.+)\t(.)/\1i\\\2/p' |
sed -f - file1
```

This solution makes a sed script from file1 and file2 which uses the line numbers from file1 where the line begins `Input:` and combines that with the respective line in file2 as an insert command.

If there is always a `Result:` following an `Input:` then the following solution would be acceptable.

```
sed -e '/Input:/R file2' -e '//h;//d' -e 'x;/./p;z;x' file1
```

Yet another way:

```
sed '/Input:/i\insert here' file1 | sed -e '/^insert here/R file2' -e '//d'
```